# Parse Server with Mailgun integration does not send out emails?

Tags: ios, parse-server

I have a Parse Server defined on my server. It runs no problem and I am sure I configured it well. I get back a status code of 200 (image below), when I generate a 'lost password' email from my iOS app, but I don't get the email.

```
@IBAction func forgotPasswordButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    PFUser()
    var email = emailTextField.text
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: email!)
}
```

Server-side code:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/asd',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'asd',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'asd',
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://asd.io:5088/parse',  
liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Users"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
},
verifyUserEmails: true,
publicServerURL: 'https://asd.io:5088/parse',
appName: 'asd',
emailAdapter: {
module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
options: {
fromAddress: 'general@*mydomain*.io',
domain: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/*mydomain*.io',
apiKey: '*key*',
}}})
```

[200 status code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpJN1.png)

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this and let me know if your email is sent to you? (access it by going to your server url)

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Email sent!');
    var api_key = 'key-***';
    var domain = '***.mailgun.org';

    var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

    var data = {
    from: 'YOU <postmaster@***.mailgun.org>',
    to: '***@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Welcome to ***!',
    text: 'Please confirm your email! New Mailgun :)'
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: I can't believe this. it was only the "domain:" key that was wrong.. had to set it to my domain. thanks for ur help anyway